# Uses of an extension and a Plugin in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to understand the functionality difference between an extension and a plugin in PostgreSQL.
With my limited understanding I found that an Extension is built with the source code and loaded using a control file using `Create extension extension_name command`.

```
# extension_name
comment = 'extension purpose'
default_version = '1.0'
module_pathname = '$libdir/extension_name'
relocatable = true
```

Whereas plugin, we can build same as an Extension but load the library by modifying the `postgresql.conf` file as follows.

```
shared_preload_libraries = '$libdir/plugin_name'    # (change requires restart)
```

Please correct my above understanding if I got it wrong. I want to understand how do we decide that feature should be made as extension or a Plugin in PostgreSQL? I couldn't find much on internet regarding Plugins, Is there any reference I can use to understand it better?

Comment: I cannot find [any reference to "plugin" in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/search/?u=%2Fdocs%2F15%2F&q=plugin), unless you are talking about logical decoding plugins?

Comment: @Bergi, I have came across another plugin, which advises potentially useful indexes after analysing given query, but that is a Proprietary software. Even if we take logical decoding plugin in consideration, I was hoping there is some kind of framework in PostgreSQL which can help in understanding use cases of both plugins and extensions.

Answer (score 0):

If the extension needs to change the behavior of the server before it has been "invoked" by a user in that session, then it needs to be preloaded.  For example pg_stat_statement collects stats on all statements being run, even in sessions which have never themselves inspected the view with the same name, so to do this is needs to be preloaded.  Extension which can get their job done without preloading will generally do just that--they will get loaded when the required feature is first called for in each session.